# how to unblock specific usb port

Tags: c#

I have block all usb through this code. It will block all usb port.

```
        RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey
            ("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\UsbStor",true);
        if (key != null)
        {
            key.SetValue("Start", 4, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }
        key.Close();
```

and unblock with this code.but it unblock all usb port.

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey
            ("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\UsbStor", true);
        if (key != null)
        {
            key.SetValue("Start", 3, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }
        key.Close();
```

My problem is to unblock only specific usb port. How we unblock only one usb port.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible to differenciate a port from another, since USB is a bus.